# phantomjs - open page does nothing

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

I spent a lot of time to narrow down the problem I faced.
I am doing my first project on phantomjs and can't execute even simple example
Could anybody try on your working version of phantomjs ?

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://phantomjs.org/';
page.open(url, function() { console.log("UAHH"); phantom.exit();});
```

I feel I miss something really simple.
I've put handlers on onResourceError, osResourceReceived, onResourceRequested and getting following results.

```
= onResourceError()
  - unable to load url: "http://phantomjs.org/"
  - error code: 5, description: Operation canceled
= onResourceReceived()
  id: 4, stage: "end", response: {"contentType":null,"headers":[],"id":4,"redirectURL":null,"stage":"end","status":null,"statusText":null,"time":"2016-12-14T00:57:18.222Z","url":"http://phantomjs.org/"}
= onResourceRequested()
  request: {
    "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/538.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) PhantomJS/2.0.0 Safari/538.1"
        }
    ],
    "id": 5,
    "method": "GET",
    "time": "2016-12-14T00:57:18.222Z",


    "url": "http://phantomjs.org/" }
```

Comment: Maybe `AppArmor / SELinux` is causing this problem? your simple example is working, it prints `UAHH`

Comment: which OS is it happening on? which phantomjs version?

Comment: It happens under gentoo. Phantomjs 2.0.0. It seems like it's definitely a problem with selinux under gentoo though I haven't solved it yet. Btw, I've found that zombiejs just works, no problems :) One of my colleagues adviced me to check this library :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens under gentoo. Phantomjs 2.0.0. It seems like it's definitely a problem with selinux under gentoo though I haven't solved it yet. Btw, I've found that zombiejs just works, no problems :) One of my colleagues adviced me to check this library :)